# 3D Acceleration Virtualbox 5.2.18 bug on Macbook Pro 2018, 15"

Tags: memory, mouse, graphics, virtualization, virtualbox

### Background

I have been having two different issues related to the performance of my virtual machines running on my brand new MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018). Given the specifications of my new Mac, there shouldn't be any issues running a simple Ubuntu 16.04 LTS instance.

The Specifications of my Host device:

- 2.9GHz Intel Core i9, 6 core processor
- 32 GB of 2400 MHz DDR4 RAM
- 1TB NVME SSD
- Radeon Pro 560X 4096 MB, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB
- Mac OS Mojave 10.14

The Specifications of my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Guest:

- 8 GB of RAM
- 2 CPU Cores
- 16MB of VRAM
- Virtualbox Guest Additions installed
- Virtualbox Extension Pack installed

### Issues

However, when I boot my Ubuntu instance I get the following two bugs.

1. "Enabling 3D Acceleration" causes the screen to detach (See the following image).

   **Steps to reproduce**:

   1. Install an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS guest on a Mac host.
   2. Enabling 3D Acceleration in Settings > Display > Screen.
   3. Boot the Linux guest.

[image: preview]

2. If "3D Acceleration" is not enabled, the Linux Guest is graphically laggy.

[image: preview]